# django order_by query set, ascending and descending

Tags: python, django, sorting

How can I order by descending my query set in django by date?

```
Reserved.objects.all().filter(client=client_id).order_by('check_in')
```

I just want to filter from descending all the Reserved by check_in date.

Answer (score 888, accepted):

```
Reserved.objects.filter(client=client_id).order_by('-check_in')
```

Notice the `-` before `check_in`.

**`-` before column name mean "descending order", while without `-` mean "ascending".**

[Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

Comment: models.somModalName.all().order_b('-date/time')

Comment: `-` before column name mean descending order without `-` mean ascending.

Comment: what if i want to order by query param? I mean if "order=asc" then i want to order by ascending and if "order=desc" then order by descending! Instead of using "if/else" is there any way to pass **asc** or **desc** to any parameter and then order according to that?

Answer (score 89):

```
Reserved.objects.filter(client=client_id).order_by('-check_in')
```

A hyphen "-" in front of "check_in" indicates descending order. Ascending order is implied.

We don't have to add an all() before filter(). That would still work, but you only need to add all() when you want all objects from the root QuerySet.

More on this here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters

Answer (score 45):

Adding the - will order it in descending order.
You can also set this by adding a default ordering to the meta of your model. This will mean that when you do a query you just do `MyModel.objects.all()` and it will come out in the correct order.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    check_in = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-check_in',)
```

Answer (score 31):

You can also use the following instruction:

```
Reserved.objects.filter(client=client_id).order_by('check_in').reverse()
```

Comment: You can, but I strongly suspect that it be more efficient to let the SQL server handle the order, at least in theory. It's nice and clear, though.

Answer (score 20):

for ascending order:

```
Reserved.objects.filter(client=client_id).order_by('check_in')
```

for descending order:

```
1.  Reserved.objects.filter(client=client_id).order_by('-check_in')
```

or

```
2.  Reserved.objects.filter(client=client_id).order_by('check_in')[::-1]
```

Comment: Why would anyone ever want to use the 2nd method?

Comment: That's one of the available choices. But, better approach is to use 1st method.

Comment: The 2nd one will return a list, not a queryset.

Comment: @ruohola yes, it will return list

Answer (score 9):

1. Ascending order

   ```
   Reserved.objects.all().filter(client=client_id).order_by('check_in')
   ```
2. Descending order

   ```
   Reserved.objects.all().filter(client=client_id).order_by('-check_in')
   ```

`-` (hyphen) is used to indicate descending order here.

Comment: You could save some queries by just calling filter

Answer (score 8):

If for some reason you have null values you can use the F function like this:

`from django.db.models import F`

`Reserved.objects.all().filter(client=client_id).order_by(F('check_in').desc(nulls_last=True))`

So it will put last the null values.
Documentation by Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-to-sort-null-values

Answer (score 7):

This is very easy and simple just follow the below instruction.

----- This for Descending

```
Reserved.objects.filter(client=client_id).order_by('-check_in')
```

------This for Ascending

```
Reserved.objects.filter(client=client_id).order_by('check_in')
```

if you want to select by Descending just add minus operator before the attribute field or if you want to select by Ascending  no need minus operator.

Answer (score 6):

```
Reserved.objects.filter(client=client_id).earliest('check_in')
```

Or alternatively

```
Reserved.objects.filter(client=client_id).latest('-check_in')
```

Here is the documentations for [`earliest()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#earliest) and [`latest()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
Staffs.objects.filter(active=1).order_by('rank')
```

**-** (hyphen) is used to indicate descending orde.

Answer (score 3):

**Order By Ascending:**

**Structure:**

```
Model.objects.filter(model_column_name=model_column_value).order_by(expected_column_name as string)
```

**Example:**

```
Employee.objects.filter(department=department_id).order_by('salary')
```

**Order By Descending:**

**Structure:**

```
Model.objects.filter(model_column_name=model_column_value).order_by(-expected_column_name as string)
```

**Example:**

```
Employee.objects.filter(department=department_id).order_by('-salary')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me.

```
latestsetuplist = SetupTemplate.objects.order_by('-creationTime')[:10][::1]
```