# How to use Lower() to sort a queryset in reverse order

Tags: django

If I don't use the `Lower()` function when sorting a queryset, then my queryset sorts uppercase and lowercase values separately. So if my queryset contains "Apples, Bananas, cherries, Oranges" and I use `order_by('name')` then I get: "Apples, Bananas, Oranges, cherries". If I use `order_by(Lower('name'))` then all works fine.

My problem is that my view sorts using `MyModel.objects.all().order_by(order_by)` where `order_by` is set using a user specified GET variable. `Lower()` errors when the GET variable tries to sort in reverse order, eg `order_by='-name'`

I tried the following code but I get a traceback error when `order_by='-name'`, but works fine when `order_by='name'`: `MyModel.objects.all().order_by(Lower(order_by))`

I then tried something smarter, but now when `order_by='-name'` then the queryset stops sorting alphabetically and just sorts using the object ID. But sorts fine when `order_by='name'`.

Views.py

```
@login_required
def merchantgroups_show_all(request):
    order_by = request.GET.get('order_by', 'name')




    from django.db.models.functions import Lower
    if order_by[0]=='-':
        order_by = order_by[1:]
        merchant_groups = MerchantGroup.objects.all().order_by('-'+Lower(order_by))
    else:
        merchant_groups = MerchantGroup.objects.all().order_by(Lower(order_by))




    paginator = Paginator(merchant_groups,20)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    merchant_groups2 = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'monzo/merchantgroups_show_all.html', {'merchant_groups': merchant_groups2,})
```

Any ideas on how to get `Lower()` to work when the GET variable `order_by` starts with a negative value?

Comment: I suggest you either apply `lower()` or `upper()` before storing the value in the database, this way you avoid the issue you have now

Comment: Can you try `Lower('-' + order_by)`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9834038, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3409047

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to `annotate` with the lowered name and order by that:

```
merchant_groups = MerchantGroup.objects.all().annotate(lower_name=Lower("name")).order_by("-lower_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Django's queryset API actually has a [reverse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#reverse) method, so you can do the following:

```py
MyModel.objects.order_by(Lower('name')).reverse()
```

The resulting SQL looks something like this (removed table names for clarity):

```sql
SELECT ... FROM "myapp_mymodel" ORDER BY LOWER("name") DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since `Lower` implements [Django's Expression API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#expression-api) you could do something like this to save the unnecessary annotation:

```py
MerchantGroup.objects.all().order_by(Lower('name').desc())

# and if the model is nullable... and you wanted them at the end:
MerchantGroup.objects.all().order_by(Lower('name').desc(nulls_last=True))
```