# How would I print a model fields from oldest to newest?

Tags: python, django

I've created a budget app that lists your income and expenses. And instead of listing most recent evemts at the top it lists them in the bottom. Is there anyway I could reverse the list or sort by most recent?

Here are some of my folders and my django project. Let me know if I need to add any others, I'm a beginner.

[HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmHmZ.png)

[Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRRL1.png)

[Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rvvH.png)

[Django Project, as you can see the most recent are at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLz95.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django order\_by query set, ascending and descending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834038/django-order-by-query-set-ascending-and-descending)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order_by()` on your queryset.
So it would be like this

```py
payment = Payment.objects.order_by("-date_created")
```

Notice the presence of  **"-"** in arguments, which implies descending order and otherwise ascending order. You call also use `.desc()`

Comment: Works perfectly!