# How can I show newest posts and comments on the top in my blogging website?

Tags: python, django

I have successfully made the models for both comments and posts and they are showing up properly on the webpage but I want the newest post to be showed up first and the same for comments as well.

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from blog.models import Post, BlogComment
from django.contrib import messages


# Create your views here.

def blogHome(request):
    allpost = Post.objects.all()
    context = {'allposts': allpost}
    return render(request, 'blog/blogHome.html', context)


def blogPost(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    comments = BlogComment.objects.filter(post=post)
    context = {'post': post, 'comments': comments}
    return render(request, 'blog/blogPost.html', context)

def postComment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = request.POST.get('comment')
        user = request.user
        postSno = request.POST.get("postSno")
        post = Post.objects.get(sno=postSno)

        comment = BlogComment(comment=comment, user=user, post=post)
        comment.save()
        messages.success(request, 'your comment has been added')

        return redirect(f"/blog/{post.slug}")
```

this is the blog home page where I want the newest post to be displayed first
**blogHome.html**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} blogs {% endblock title %}
{% block blogactive %}active {% endblock blogactive %}
{% block body %}

<h2 class="text-center my-4">blogs by everythingcs</h2>
<div class="container">
  {% for post in allposts %}
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
      <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
        <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">by-{{post.author}}</strong>
        <h3 class="mb-0">{{post.title}}</h3>
        <div class="mb-1 text-muted">Nov 12</div>
        <p class="card-text mb-auto">{{post.content|truncatechars:200}}</p>
        <div class="my-2">
          <a href="/blog/{{post.slug}}" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">More..</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock body %}
```

finally the **models.py** for further reference:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + " by " + self.author


class BlogComment(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    comment = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment[0:13] + "..." + "by " + self.user.username
```

in short, I want to sort my blog post and blog comments by their time and then display them accordingly.

Comment: you can keep a DB field like `timeStamp` that you can update every time a post is edited and `order_by` that field when showing all the posts.

Comment: Take a look at this article. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834038/django-order-by-query-set-ascending-and-descending. I hope it solves your problem

Comment: Take a look at this article. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834038/django-order-by-query-set-ascending-and-descending I hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a default [**`ordering`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) in the [**`Meta`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#model-meta-options) of the objects:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} by {self.author}'


class BlogComment(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    comment = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.comment[0:13]}... by {self.user.username}'
```

or you can order explicitly:

```
def blogHome(request):
    allpost = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')
    context = {'allposts': allpost}
    return render(request, 'blog/blogHome.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `timestamp` instead of <s>`timeStamp`</s>.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.